# How to check if a file is uploaded in Imacro

Tags: vbscript, imacros

Using Imacros and VBscript for firefox. How to I test once a file has been uploaded.

What I want to be able to do is test for a page change and then see if a specific text is in the page if it is great close the browser, if not its an error and I want to leave it open to come back to later.

I open 1200 tabs in the process. I would like to close them if all went well.

I have different test cases for different browsers (sites).

Would be most grateful for any help anyone can give.

C

EDIT: CODE ADDED

```
TAB OPEN
TAB T=1167
URL GOTO=http://www.SOMESITE.com/login
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:login_form ATTR=ID:login_remember CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:login_form ATTR=ID:login_submit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:UPLOAD
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.SOMESITE.com/templates/frontend/blue/images/upload_video_icon.png
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:uploadVideo ATTR=ID:upload_video_title CONTENT=Some Video Title
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:uploadVideo ATTR=ID:upload_video_keywords CONTENT=key workds for video
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:uploadVideo ATTR=ID:upload_video_category CONTENT=%2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=NAME:uploadVideo ATTR=ID:upload_video_file CONTENT=D:\Web\theuploadvideo.avi
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:uploadVideo ATTR=ID:upload_video_submit
```

So with in that I want to add some code that will check when the reponse comes back from upload if its got words like upload successful, then I want it to close, else I want it to just leave it open so I can check.

1200 videos a day, so ideally I just want to check the 5 that failed not all 1200.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: So with in that I want to add some code that will check when the reponse comes back from upload if its got words like upload successful, then I want it to close, else I want it to just leave it open so I can check.

1200 videos a day, so ideally I just want to check the 5 that failed not all 1200.

Comment: Can you just use TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM to read that response? And use WAIT if it is a long response...

Comment: Is there no handler that would simply execute on a change in response, some file are 700 megs I had no way of knowing how long to wait.

Surely there is some sort of ON EVENT() handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this command line.

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP x
```

Where x is a number. So this way you will tell a macro to wait for any command a number of seconds.

Let's say you are waiting for a text "DONE" to appear on the page. So,

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:DONE CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

This macro above will wait for 6000 seconds for that text to appear. Try something with this approach.

Edit:

You can use `SET !TIMEOUT_STEP X` command like this too.

Suppose you want to wait for text "DONE" around 6000 seconds and after that you want script to continue normally.

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:DONE CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:DONE EXTRACT=TXT
```

So in this case the script will wait for 6000 seconds for the part of script that searches for text DONE . After that you will set the waiting time for 1 second and each new line you will have waiting time of just 1 second.

You can use and use over again `SET !TIMEOUT_STEP x` command in the macro and adjust waiting time the way you want.

Comment: Great thanks, one other question on this, Sorry I am an Imacro noob. The execution of this, would it delay other steps or would other tab commands happen asynchronously ?

Comment: I will edit the main answer and show you how you can do it the way you want.